# How to attach the new Process instance to the existing process?

Tags: .net, process

I have some process running. And I know its processId. I need to create a new Diagnostics.Process instance to attach to that known process. How to do that?
Languages - VB.Net or C#

Comment: As a followup, how did you attach to the process? Are you able to access static instances from the other process?

Answer (score 3):

The answer is very easy:

```
Process p = Process.GetProcessById(procId)
```